# Convert entity framework C# code to raw SQL for performance

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to check logins and logout pairs in the eventsLogs table. A pair consists one login and one logout. In the eventLogs table have many events out which I am interested in eventType 11 and 12 which means  when user logged in(event 11) and the logged out (event 12). There could be duplicate events for that user from a computer. For example, login,login ,logout, so what I am doing in C# is taking the first login and then find its pair. The problem is I do not know to do this in SQL, unfortunately I am loading all the logins and logouts into memory!. I want a way so that I could call a store procedure and get the same result which I am currently binding to a class in C#. I will highly appreciate your help. If I didn't explain my question well, please ask for explanation.

```
 // C#
   var departmentEventsDic = new Dictionary<string, List<Sessions>>();   

   //get all departments and run the loop
 foreach (var department in departments)
                    {
                        // create a list to push a pairs
                        var sessionPairsList = new List<Sessions>();
                      // for each computer in the department
                        foreach (var computer in department.Computers)
                        {

                            var  tempLogs= eventLogs.Where(x => x.ComputerId == computer.ComputerId) .OrderBy(x => x.EventDateTime).ToList();
                            var tempUnlock = DateTime.MinValue;

                            //for each log for the computer 
                            foreach (var log in tempLogs)
                            {
                                // if the event is login store it in temp varible 
                                if (log.EventType == 11)
                                {
                                    tempUnlock = log.EventDateTime;

                                }
                                // if its logout and its time is greater than tempUnlock , found a pair create class and add to list 
                                if (log.EventType == 12 && (tempUnlock != DateTime.MinValue) && log.EventDateTime > tempUnlock)
                                {
                                    var sessionPair = new Sessions
                                    {
                                        DepartmentId = department.DepartmentId,
                                        DepartmentName = department.DepartmentName,
                                        ComputerId = computer.ComputerId,
                                        ComputerName = computer.Name,
                                        LoginTime = tempUnlock,
                                        LogOutTime = log.EventDateTime,
                                        UserId = department.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == log.UserId)?.UserId,
                                        UserName = department.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == log.UserId)?.Name,
                                        Difference = (log.EventDateTime - temUnlock)
                                    };
                                    sessionPairsList.Add(sessionPair);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // add to dictionary with department name as key and list of sessionspairs as values

                        departmentEventsDic.Add(department.DepartmentName, sessionPairsList);
                    }



 public class Results
    {
        public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public Guid ComputerId { get; set; }
        public string ComputerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogOutTime { get; set; }
        public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Difference { get; set; }
    }       
    //Tables
```

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Departments](
    [DepartmentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PrimaryKey,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    );
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Computers](
    [ComputerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PrimaryKey,    
    [DepartmentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL );

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Computers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Computers_Departments_DepartmentId] FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Departments] ([DepartmentId])
    ON DELETE CASCADE



     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLogs](
    [EventLogId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PrimaryKey,
    [ComputerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EventDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL);
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventLogs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventLogs_Computers_ComputerId] FOREIGN KEY([ComputerId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Computers] ([ComputerId])
    ON DELETE CASCADE



   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL);
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Departments_DepartmentId] FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Departments] ([DepartmentId])
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Please update your post to include the DB schema, and at least 30 rows of sample data. Please explain what results you would expect based on those 30 rows, and why.

Comment: There's no reason to be calling `.ToList()`, that is what is loading all of the records into memory.  Get rid of that and also add a filter for event type 11 or 12 and you'll be fine.

Comment: I doubt you need to use raw SQL - I think your problem is a lack of table indexes or other database issues. If EF is pulling the entire table into memory then you're probably not using `IQueryable` correctly (e.g. using `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` before `Where()`).

Comment: Do you want to always pull all the login/logout history or would you want to search for records after a specified date? I'm thinking about daily or weekly auditing where records from last month aren't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize operations like this greatly by using a DBContext with relationships that are oriented to the way you want to query them. In your case you have Departments /w computers, and a loose DbSet of EventLogs. A computer entity normally doesn't need a collection of eventlogs, but in the case of this report, that 1-many relationship would be useful.

If your main Context doesn't have these relationships mapped out, then you can consider a bounded context to retrieve this data using entity maps with the Computer treated as a top-level entity and each Computer has a Department, and a collection of EventLogs. Each event has a User reference based on it's UserId.

From there, EF can do all of the heavy lifting:

```
var sessionDataQuery  = dbContext.Computers
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Department.DepartmentId,
        x.Department.DepartmentName,
        x.ComputerId,
        ComputerName = x.Name,
        LoginEvents = x.EventLogs
            .OrderBy(e => e.EventDateTime)
            .Where(e => e.EventType = 11)
            .Select(e => new 
            {
                e.EventId,
                e.User.UserId,
                e.User.UserName,
                e.EventDateTime
            }.ToList(),
        LogoutEvents = x.EventLogs
            .OrderBy(e => e.EventDateTime)
            .Where(e => e.EventType = 12)
            .Select(e => new 
            {
                e.EventId,
                e.User.UserId,
                e.User.UserName,
                e.EventDateTime
            }.ToList()
     });
```

That query should produce you an IQueryable of data that you can use to start building your session details. As it will run across *all* computers you will probably want to avoid using a .ToList() on it, rather using a Take & skip /w ToList to fetch a batch of them, (I.e. 50 at a time) or iterate and select them one at a time in a Foreach.

This assumes that the event's User reference will match the Department of the computer.

From here you can assess the LoginEvents and LogoutEvents of each computer and compose the session view models for these. You'll likely need logic to marry up Logins with Logouts based on Time and handle cases where you might have a login without a logout, and vise-verse.

Assuming there was a one to one login to logout your sessing par population would be something like:

```
foreach(var computer in sessionDataQuery)
{
    for(int count = 0; count < computer.LoginEvents.Count; count++)
    {
       var loginEvent = computer.LoginEvents[count];
       var logoutEvent = computer.LogoutEvents[count];
       sessionPairs.Add( new Sessons
       {
          DepartmentId = computer.DepartmentId,
          DepartmentName = computer.DepartmentName,
          ComputerId = computer.ComputerId,
          ComputerName = computer.ComputerName,
          LoginTime = loginEvent.EventDateTime,
          LogoutTime = logoutEvent.EventDateTime,
          UserId = loginEvent.UserId,
          UserName = loginEvent.UserName,
          Difference = logoutEvent.EventDateTime - loginEvent.EventDateTime
      }
   }
}
```

That does an iteration over the query, then across the login & logout events assuming that they are paired correctly. Chances are you'll need to be a bit more selective on how you consider the events rather than relying on a for loop.

The sessionPairs would be a `List<Sessions>` and can be grouped by DepartmentID to get a set of events per department.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. The problem is while i am testing that eventLog does not contain reference to Users, just the Guid that matches the Id of user in users table. how can I join users table to get names?

Comment: A couple options: You can update the original entities and mappings to include the references. If you'd rather avoid changes to the existing entities then consider creating a bounded context to serve this calculation with a set of entities specific to this purpose mapped to the same tables. These can have the references set up to allow EF to resolve these relationships. This is the real power of an ORM to provide that ability to relate objects, let you query and select based on those relations, and produce efficient SQL to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your title states you want to convert this to SQL code.  This is all doable in TSQL, but first you will need to know the syntax to convert the C# code to TSQL.  Here I am providing all the elements which you will need to get you there.

Use Create Procedure with OUTPUT parameters if you need to return values back from the stored procedure. All parameters within a stored procedure look like @parameter with a data type.

There is no foreach statement in TSQL, but you can replace these with while loops-and nest them- but you will need to get the count of the rows you are going to parse with Select Count(*) first, store this in a variable, and then increment it each time through the while loop. (NOTE: Be careful with while loops in SQL Server stored procedures, they can bring the server to its knees if you don't have a clear exit path from the while loop.)

Your lamda statements in C# will need to be converted to a series of IF/Else statements or possibly a CASE statement in TSQL.

Temporary tables can be used in stored procedures by naming a table name with # before the name and are useful to throw values into memory and then manipulate them in some way to get the result you desire.

Hope this gives you a few more ideas toward the TSQL stored procedure solution.